# sqoop import-all-tables tool not working

Tags: sqoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

When I run below script on Cloudera VM, I am getting below error.

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" -username =retail_dba --p

6/09/17 23:33:11 ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list tables
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '=retail_dba'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myself fixed the issue

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" -username =retail_dba --p
```

In the above script, there is space between username and '='.  so sqoop assuming username as `=retail_dba.`

Its worked fine when removed empty space.